# Python / Linux Cron

Tags: python, linux, cron, server

I'm trying to run a Twitter Python script every 5 minutes from my Linux server, When I run it manually via SSH it works perfectly, but when I try to run it with a cron I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/celestia/public_html/monroe/twitter_follow_bot.py", line 222, in <module>
    auto_follow("love",count=1)
  File "/home/celestia/public_html/monroe/twitter_follow_bot.py", line 108, in auto_follow
    dnf_list.append(int(line))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Line 108 is             `dnf_list.append(int(line))`

Here is the source code
https://github.com/rhiever/twitter-follow-bot

My cron job looks like this 
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /home/celestia/public_html/elvis/twitter_follow_bot.py

Answer (score 0):

It's important that you post as much information as you can about your problem, including code.

`line` has a value of `''`.

This could be handled in your program by checking if line is not an empty string before appending to your list

```
if line:
  dnf_list.append(int(line))
```

The above can still error if `line` is not a number though

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a blank line from the file `ALREADY_FOLLOWED_FILE` which leads to the `ValueError` when you attempt to convert that to an `int`. In the code below, I catch exceptions where the int conversion fails, which should solve your problem.

```
with open(ALREADY_FOLLOWED_FILE) as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        try:
            twitter_id = int(line)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            dnf_list.append(twitter_id)
```

Comment: File "/home/celestia/public_html/elvis/twitter_follow_bot.py", line 107
    for line in in_file:
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @BradHouston removed extra space